# Is there a shortcut to Gmail Contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I often update my contact list.

Currently I have to

1. Open Gmail
2. Open contacts link

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google is very good about doing redirects with subdomains.

Have you tried [**contacts.google.com**](http://contacts.google.com)?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a keyboard shortcut:

When you are in Gmail, hit <kbd>g</kbd> immediately followed by <kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: You have to [enable additional keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594) for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one but very hard to remember though...

https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/#contacts

Updated

Now just go for `google.com/contacts`

Comment: You can leave off the last part of that URL and just use `google.com/contacts`. You will be redirected automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I agree ^^ It didn't work it that way before. Now it does.