# What is the single/alone URL for Hangouts chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

I want to have the URL for Hangouts, in order to open it directly, similar to the one used for [Google Contact](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36632/is-there-a-shortcut-to-gmail-contacts).

That is, I don't want the Hangouts to be a popup to the G+ site. Is such thing available?

ps.

I wan to pin it on my taskbar as a shortcut to application - a feature of Chrome browser.

[image]

Comment: As in https://plus.google.com/hangouts ?

Comment: @Alex Nope for two things. 1) Not available in Vietnam my country http://imgur.com/DvA6mF8 and 2) I cannot pin it on taskbar in Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

http://hangouts.google.com

## Explanation

When this answer was originally posted, there was not a Google Hangouts standalone app. It was launched in August 2015. On the first days, the 'hangouts.google.com' redirected to 'talkgadget.google.com' but nowadays the redirection was removed.

### Other ways to access to Hangouts

Besides the standalone web app, it's possible to access Hangouts from the desktop without going to Gmail or Google+ web sites:

- [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd)
- [Chrome desktop app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl)

## References

- [We are launching another way to use Hangouts today](https://plus.google.com/+JordannaChord/posts/fggYXgnfu4K) Google+ post from [Jordanna Chord](https://plus.google.com/106795562240032292110) on August 17, 2015.
- [Hangouts services to be served from 'hangouts.google.com' - Google Apps update alerts](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/09/hangouts-services-to-be-served-from.html).